# How to Validate Signature with SigScript length 8b?

Tags: signature, validation, error, input-script

I created a raw Transaction:

010000000146460fc2adc04c8eefd1e14bbaa2ad683481bb5fdf95d0d4bf847cc78cbc9ff1000000001976a9145e4f04c3ee1941d665eb1312280ca3a0bbbfd3ba88acffffffff02801a0600000000001976a914befa5e3cf184ee71974f9b3a7580bed1816b0d4588ac801a0600000000001976a9145e4f04c3ee1941d665eb1312280ca3a0bbbfd3ba88ac0000000001000000

After Generating Digital Signature:

3045022100cd89b747b9507cb525c5d2d48aa7ebc8941c257621219471dab1e23c6280f99502204823508b23dc61e2868c120f1b90da864902266a3d2ae087720d26e5313d788a

Final SigScript Value is:

8b493045022100a8b021691b6cf9a61f7ad8e4ffa9596e668e14e4e14e29ef17f9f49276722e4e02201ccb70bc0748ff16841cd68a781dc3511fffea76febcb735fe78a4a270023f830141049ea82ac663a76fb872d4a49674762c3f9e60e25d55f7636d76b03efef3d69e838ab749455d3951aa015ccac729ecd9d656e596686af6204534821699e779534b

So, Final Broadcasting Transaction is:

010000000146460fc2adc04c8eefd1e14bbaa2ad683481bb5fdf95d0d4bf847cc78cbc9ff100000000**8b493045022100a8b021691b6cf9a61f7ad8e4ffa9596e668e14e4e14e29ef17f9f49276722e4e02201ccb70bc0748ff16841cd68a781dc3511fffea76febcb735fe78a4a270023f830141049ea82ac663a76fb872d4a49674762c3f9e60e25d55f7636d76b03efef3d69e838ab749455d3951aa015ccac729ecd9d656e596686af6204534821699e779534b**ffffffff02801a0600000000001976a914befa5e3cf184ee71974f9b3a7580bed1816b0d4588ac801a0600000000001976a9145e4f04c3ee1941d665eb1312280ca3a0bbbfd3ba88ac00000000

This Gives error in Validating Signature.

But if my SigScript(i.e. generating Signature of length 8a, instead of length  8b) is
8a47304402205054d068fdcb34e409fa6978ea7ae9612286356f1d273e8fc0b1012e0aa606b102201e0b7dee3cab6448f77186585d9e765450dc424386e4c237b153a08ebe9d56080141049ea82ac663a76fb872d4a49674762c3f9e60e25d55f7636d76b03efef3d69e838ab749455d3951aa015ccac729ecd9d656e596686af6204534821699e779534b

Broadcasting Transaction is 
010000000146460fc2adc04c8eefd1e14bbaa2ad683481bb5fdf95d0d4bf847cc78cbc9ff100000000**8a47304402205054d068fdcb34e409fa6978ea7ae9612286356f1d273e8fc0b1012e0aa606b102201e0b7dee3cab6448f77186585d9e765450dc424386e4c237b153a08ebe9d56080141049ea82ac663a76fb872d4a49674762c3f9e60e25d55f7636d76b03efef3d69e838ab749455d3951aa015ccac729ecd9d656e596686af6204534821699e779534b**ffffffff02801a0600000000001976a914befa5e3cf184ee71974f9b3a7580bed1816b0d4588ac801a0600000000001976a9145e4f04c3ee1941d665eb1312280ca3a0bbbfd3ba88ac00000000

The Transaction is successfully broadcasted (TXid):

```
0377531e44690a2a114f6b6874368de488911cb6ad452292add3d252344e24c5
```

Could somebody please explain how to broadcast transaction with length SigScript lenght 8b?
Thank you

Comment: If you check the `scriptSig` in the first case, you are pushing `0x49` bytes after `0x8b` which is consuming the byte the contains the length of the public key (byte `0x41`). Use `0x48` after `0x8b` and it will work.

Comment: Thank you Ugam Kamat! It worked Perfectly.